# Python list from .txt file

Tags: python

I`m trying to create primitive dictionary (or list) in Python with basic functions that I learned from book (Mark Summerfield).

Here is my question.

All works as I need, but I had a problem with writing strings to the file.

This is a piece of my code:

```
  word = input("New word is: ") #adding new word
  if word:
       word.strip() #erasing new str from any symbols
       x = len(word)
       numeration = str(count) + ". " 
       word = word[:0] + numeration + word[0:] # =to sort as list
       word = word[:x] + ",\n" # =adding shift to the end of str
       file = open("test.txt", "a") # =wriing to the file 
       file.write(word)
       file.close()
       count += 1
```

Problem shows itself in the output:

```
======================== RESTART: /home/z177/test.py ========================
Type word to add word, type nothing to read dict, ^D\Z to quit
New word is: currently raining
New word is: currently not
New word is: 
1. currently rain,
2. currently ,
```

It is overwriting the last 3 symbols in the string.

I've solved this problem by replacing

```
word[:x] + ",\n"
```

with

```
word + ",\n"
```

I am still interested why the code is replacing these 3 symbols when I add new symbols to the end of the string.

Can you explain this?

Comment: Hi @umeeo, What are you trying to achieve with this: word = word[:0] + numeration + word[0:]

Comment: X is the original length before adding 3 characters to the front, so it truncated 3 characters at the end.

Comment: Just do `word = numeration + word + ',\n'`.

Comment: Wow, that much easier. Thank you all, guys, you are cool! Hello @EliasMP, it is planned to adds the numeration like '1. 2. 3' in the beginning of string.

Comment: Yep, I only wanted to know for helping you but our colleagues took advantage... :P. Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is created in this line:

```
word = word[:x] + ",\n" # =adding shift to the end of str
```

You need to remember that variable `word` isn't contain your word any more. You have there for example "0. word" there.

So you have to update `x` - line count to get correct results in your file.

Answer (score 1):

The length of word has increased after inserting `numeration`, so `x` holds the value of the old length before the update. You should move the line where `x` is assigned after the update:

```
numeration = str(count) + ". " 
word = numeration + word[0:] # length of word changes here
x = len(word)
word = word[:x] + ",\n"
```

Or stick to using `word = word + ",\n"` which is less verbose and still does the same thing.

---

The entire logic can however be simplified into the following:

```
word = numeration + word + ',\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you set `x` to be the length of the input word, but then add `numeration` to the string, making it several characters longer (three characters, in the case of a single-digit `count`). If you were to change

```
word = word[:x] + ",\n" # =adding shift to the end of str
```

to

```
word = word[:len(word)] + ",\n"
```

You should get the correct result.

Unrelated to your issue, the code you presented is very un-Pythonic, and when you've mastered the logic of the program I'd take a look at refactoring, using [`with open('test.txt', 'a') as file:`](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) over the explicit `file.close()` and using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) over concatenation.